# ArcMap arrow symbol for point: how to make the arrow end starts from the point instead of sitting in the middle of point?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I am trying to use arrows to display points. The arcmap worked nicely to rotate arrow according to the angle field (layer property/symbology/advanced/rotation), however the middle of the arrow sit on the point. I want the arrow to start from point. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the offset of your symbol. This may allow you to point your arrow directly at your points.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem. I am aware of offset but somehow I thought it would not work when rotated. I was wrong. Thank you so much!